# dataTable primeFaces mostra o numero de registros corretos mas não mostra os campos

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

estou com um problema que não consigo solucionar se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

Em resumo é um protótipo de cadastro de nota fiscal com itens de notafiscal,  eu consigo inserir os registros através de um dialog,  a tabela mostra que os registros foram inseridos na lista, mas o dataTable mostra as linhas sem os conteúdos.

segue os arquivos.

```
package br.com.beta.nfe.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "notaFiscal")
public class NotaFiscal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private Integer numero;
    private Date dataEmissao;
    private Emissor emissor;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private List<ItemNotaFiscal> itensNotaFiscal = new ArrayList<>();
    @Column(columnDefinition = "double")
    private BigDecimal vrTotalNotaFiscal;
    private String  observacao;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "notaFiscalGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "notaFiscalGenerator", sequenceName = "NOTAFISCAL_SEQ", allocationSize = 10)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(Integer numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "data_emissao", nullable = false)
    public Date getDataEmissao() {
        return dataEmissao;
    }

    public void setDataEmissao(Date dataEmissao) {
        this.dataEmissao = dataEmissao;
    }

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "emissor_id", nullable = false)
    public Emissor getEmissor() {
        return emissor;
    }

    public void setEmissor(Emissor emissor) {
        this.emissor = emissor;
    }

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cliente_id", nullable = false)
    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<ItemNotaFiscal> getItensNotaFiscal() {
        for (ItemNotaFiscal inf : this.itensNotaFiscal) {
            System.out
                    .println("listando os itens da table !" +inf.getId()+" "+ inf.getItem().getDescricao()+" quantidade : "+inf.getQuantidade()+"preco : "+inf.getValorUnitario());
        }
        return itensNotaFiscal;
    }

    public void setItensNotaFiscal(List<ItemNotaFiscal> itensNotaFiscal) {
        this.itensNotaFiscal = itensNotaFiscal;
    }


    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "valor_total_nota", nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 2)
    public BigDecimal getVrTotalNotaFiscal() {
        return vrTotalNotaFiscal;
    }

    public void setVrTotalNotaFiscal(BigDecimal vrTotalNotaFiscal) {
        this.vrTotalNotaFiscal = vrTotalNotaFiscal;
    }

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    public String getObservacao() {
        return observacao;
    }

    public void setObservacao(String observacao) {
        this.observacao = observacao;
    }


    public void recalcularValorTotal() {
        BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;



        for (ItemNotaFiscal itemNotaFiscal : this.getItensNotaFiscal()) {
            if (itemNotaFiscal.getItem() != null && itemNotaFiscal.getItem().getId() != null) {
                total = total.add(itemNotaFiscal.getTotalItem());
            }
        }

        this.setVrTotalNotaFiscal(total);
    }

    public void adicionarItemNotaFiscal(ItemNotaFiscal itemNotaFiscal) {

            this.getItensNotaFiscal().add(itemNotaFiscal);

    }

    @Transient
    public BigDecimal getValorSubtotal() {
        //return this.getValorTotal().subtract(this.getValorFrete()).add(this.getValorDesconto());
        return this.getVrTotalNotaFiscal();
    }

    @Transient
    public boolean isNovo() {
        return getId() == null;
    }

    @Transient
    public boolean isExistente() {
        return !isNovo();
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        NotaFiscal other = (NotaFiscal) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }





}
```

O bean :

```
package br.com.beta.nfe.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;

import br.com.beta.nfe.model.Cliente;
import br.com.beta.nfe.model.Item;
import br.com.beta.nfe.model.ItemNotaFiscal;
import br.com.beta.nfe.model.NotaFiscal;
import br.com.beta.nfe.repository.Clientes;
import br.com.beta.nfe.repository.Itens;
import br.com.beta.nfe.service.CadastroNotaFiscalService;
import br.com.beta.nfe.service.NegocioException;
import br.com.beta.nfe.util.jsf.FacesUtil;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroNotaFiscalBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Clientes clientes;

    @Inject
    private Itens itens;

    @Inject
    private Item item;

    @Inject
    private CadastroNotaFiscalService cadastroNotaFiscalService;

    @Inject NotaFiscal notaFiscal;

    private String codigoSKU;
    private BigDecimal valorUnitario;
    private Double quantidade;
    private Item itemLinhaEditavel;


    public CadastroNotaFiscalBean() {
        limpar();
    }

    public void inicializar() {
        if (FacesUtil.isNotPostback()) {
            if (this.notaFiscal == null) {
                limpar();
                // this.notaFiscal.adicionarItemVazio();
                // this.recalcularNotaFiscal();
            }
            // this.notaFiscal.adicionarItemVazio();
            this.recalcularNotaFiscal();

        }
    }

    public void handleSelect(SelectEvent event) {

        item = (Item) event.getObject();
        System.out.println("selecionou o item - > " + item.getDescricao());
        this.valorUnitario = item.getVrUnitario();
        System.out.println("o Item " + item.getDescricao()
                + " tem o preço unitario de -> " + item.getVrUnitario());
    }

    public void onItemSelect(Item selecionado) {

        item = selecionado;
    }

    public void insereItenNotaFiscal(ActionEvent actionEvent){

        ItemNotaFiscal itemNotaFiscal = new ItemNotaFiscal();
        itemNotaFiscal.setItem(item);
        itemNotaFiscal.setValorUnitario(item.getVrUnitario());
        itemNotaFiscal.setNotaFiscal(this.notaFiscal);
        itemNotaFiscal.setQuantidade(this.quantidade);
        Long ordem = (long) (this.notaFiscal.getItensNotaFiscal().size()+1);
        itemNotaFiscal.setId(ordem);

        this.notaFiscal.adicionarItemNotaFiscal(itemNotaFiscal);

        for (ItemNotaFiscal inf : this.notaFiscal.getItensNotaFiscal()) {
            System.out
                    .println("inseri o item !" + inf.getId()+" "+inf.getItem().getCodigoSKU()+" "+inf.getItem().getDescricao()+" "+inf.getValorUnitario()+" "+inf.getQuantidade());
        }
    }

    private void limpar() {
        notaFiscal = new NotaFiscal();

    }

    public void salvar() {
        try {
            this.notaFiscal = cadastroNotaFiscalService.salvar(this.notaFiscal);
            limpar();

            FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Produto salvo com sucesso!");
        } catch (NegocioException ne) {
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(ne.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void recalcularNotaFiscal() {
        if (this.notaFiscal != null) {
            this.notaFiscal.recalcularValorTotal();
        }
    }

    public void carregarItemPorCodigoSKU() {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(this.codigoSKU)) {
            this.itemLinhaEditavel = this.itens.porCodigoSKU(this.codigoSKU);
            this.carregarItemLinhaEditavel();
        }
    }

    public void carregarItemLinhaEditavel() {
        ItemNotaFiscal itemNotaFiscal = this.notaFiscal.getItensNotaFiscal()
                .get(0);

        if (this.itemLinhaEditavel != null) {
            if (this.existeItemNotaFiscalComItem(this.itemLinhaEditavel)) {
                FacesUtil
                        .addErrorMessage("Já existe um item na Nota Fiscal com o item informado.");
            } else {
                itemNotaFiscal.setItem(this.itemLinhaEditavel);
                itemNotaFiscal.setValorUnitario(this.itemLinhaEditavel
                        .getVrUnitario());

                // this.notaFiscal.adicionarItemVazio();
                this.itemLinhaEditavel = null;
                this.codigoSKU = null;

                this.notaFiscal.recalcularValorTotal();
            }
        }

    }

    private boolean existeItemNotaFiscalComItem(Item item) {
        boolean existeItemNotaFiscal = false;

        for (ItemNotaFiscal itemNotaFiscal : this.getNotaFiscal()
                .getItensNotaFiscal()) {
            if (item.equals(itemNotaFiscal.getItem())) {
                existeItemNotaFiscal = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return existeItemNotaFiscal;
    }

    public List<Item> completarItem(String descricao) {
        return this.itens.porDescricao(descricao);
    }

    public List<Cliente> completarCliente(String nome) {
        return this.clientes.porNome(nome);
    }

    public NotaFiscal getNotaFiscal() {
        return notaFiscal;
    }

    public void setNotaFiscal(NotaFiscal notafiscal) {
        this.notaFiscal = notaFiscal;

    }

    public boolean isEditando() {
        return this.notaFiscal.getId() != null;
    }

    public Item getItemLinhaEditavel() {
        return itemLinhaEditavel;
    }

    public void setItemLinhaEditavel(Item itemLinhaEditavel) {
        this.itemLinhaEditavel = itemLinhaEditavel;
    }

    public String getCodigoSKU() {
        return codigoSKU;
    }

    public void setCodigoSKU(String codigoSKU) {
        this.codigoSKU = codigoSKU;
    }

    public Double getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(Double quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorUnitario() {
        return valorUnitario;
    }

    public void setValorUnitario(BigDecimal valorUnitario) {
        this.valorUnitario = valorUnitario;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }



}
```

o xhtml que apresenta a tabela :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <p:commandButton value="Incluir Itens" type="button"
        onclick="PF('insereItem').show();" />


    <p:dataTable id="tabelaItens"
        value="#{cadastroNotaFiscalBean.notaFiscal.itensNotaFiscal}" 
        var="tabelaItens" style="margin-top: 20px"
        emptyMessage="Nenhum item encontrado." rows="20">
        <p:column headerText="Ordem">
            <h:outputText value="#{itemNotaFiscal.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Item">
            <h:outputText value="#{itemNotaFiscal.item.descricao}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Valor unitario">
            <h:outputText value="#{itemNotaFiscal.valorUnitario}">
                <f:convertNumber type="currency" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Quantidade">
            <h:outputText size="8" value="#{itemNotaFiscal.quantidade}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dialog id="insereItem" header="Inclusão de Itens"
        widgetVar="insereItem" modal="true" height="300" width="500">

        <h:outputText value="Inclusão de Item" />
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel"
            style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">


            <p:outputLabel value="Item" for="item" />
            <p:autoComplete id="item" size="40" dropdown="true"
                value="#{cadastroNotaFiscalBean.item}"
                completeMethod="#{cadastroNotaFiscalBean.completarItem}" var="item"
                itemLabel="#{item.descricao}" itemValue="#{item}"
                forceSelection="true">
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
                    listener="#{cadastroNotaFiscalBean.handleSelect}"
                    update="valorUnitario" render="valorUnitario" />
                <p:ajax event="change"
                    listener="#{cadastroNotaFiscalBean.handleSelect}"
                    update="valorUnitario" render="valorUnitario" />


            </p:autoComplete>

            <p:outputLabel value="Valor Unitario" for="valorUnitario" />
            <p:outputLabel autoUpdate="true" id="valorUnitario" size="15"
                value="#{cadastroNotaFiscalBean.valorUnitario}" />


            <p:outputLabel value="Quantidade" for="quantidade" />
            <p:inputText id="quantidade" size="8"
                value="#{cadastroNotaFiscalBean.quantidade}" />

        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton update="tabelaItens"
            oncomplete="PF('insereItem').hide();"
            actionListener="#{cadastroNotaFiscalBean.insereItenNotaFiscal}"
            value="Inserir Item">

        </p:commandButton>
    </p:dialog>



</ui:composition>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloquei os screenshots da tela do dialog e da tabela, se observarem ela apresenta a linha mas vazia. E a lista esta carregada corretamente com os itens,  testei o conteúdo com um for  e esta ok.

Se puderem me dar uma luz, agradeço.

Comment: Uma coisa que achei estranho é: `var="tabelaItens"`, porém dentro do dataTable você utiliza apenas o `#{itemNotaFiscal}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo é porque você esta fazendo a chamada errada, o correto seria pela variavel var="tabelaItens".

```
var="tabelaItens", ficando assim:

<p:column headerText="Ordem">
    <h:outputText value="#{tabelaItens.id}" /> -> CORRETO
    <h:outputText value="#{itemNotaFiscal.id}" /> -> ERRADO
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Em seu datatable, onde tem `itemNotaFiscal.algumaCoisa` substitua por: `tabelaItens.algumaCoisa`, onde o `.algumaCoisa` será o atributo que você deseja referenciar.

Você deve utilizar a var que é definida na declaração do datatable quando desejar referenciar ao item corrente do datatable.